# Linux 3.0 TCP Stack Receive Buffer Kernel Architecture

Tags: linux, tcp, x86-64

(Linux 3.0, x86_64)

If I stop calling **recv(2)** for a while on a connected tcp socket, and the other host keeps sending data, than presumably this data is received and buffered by the kernel, so the next time I call recv it will return quickly with all the waiting data.

My question is how big is this receive buffer, and how does it work?  Are there any relevant kernel or socket settings I can use to tune its behavior?  What does the tcp stack do when it fills up?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The receive buffer can be changed with [`setsockopt(SO_RCVBUF)`](http://linux.die.net/man/7/socket). The default size is controlled by the [tcp_rmem](http://www.linuxinsight.com/proc_sys_net_ipv4_tcp_rmem.html) sysctl. If the buffer fills up, the stack will stop extending the receive window it offers to the other side, forcing the other size to stop sending data until there's space in the buffer.